# Is there a way that I can plot 3 line plots with a bar chart as a one graph with different y-axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I want to plot 3 line plots with a barchart together as one graph in python pandas. How do I plot these together with different y-axes? E.g., one line plot as a target line of the barchart, and other line plot as the target of other line plot.

So the task is to plot 4 plots as a single graph, I have 2 different variables, one is protein % which is a barchart and the other is calories which is a line plot, they both share the same x-axis which is months. Now I want to include the other 2 line plots with each as a target variable of the two defined variables above. Two line plots have to share one y-axis, and the other line plot has to share the other y-axis with the barchart. I managed to plot my two variables with different y-axes as one graph, and also managed to make one line plot to share one y-axis with one variable, but now I can't make the other line plot to share the other y-axis with the other variable.

```
from bokeh.palettes import PuBu
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ranges, LabelSet, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d
# My word count data
months = nutrients_group.Month.tolist() 
p_percentage = nutrients_group.Protein_percetange.tolist()
calories = nutrients_group.Energy.tolist()
#protein_percent = [round(x) for x in p_percentage]
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=months, y=p_percentage))

# Output the visualization directly in the notebook
#output_notebook()

# Create a figure with a datetime type x-axis
fig = figure(title='Year overview with target',
             plot_height=400, plot_width=700,
             x_axis_label='Months', y_axis_label='Calories',
             x_minor_ticks=2,
             toolbar_location=None)







#labels = LabelSet(x=months, y=p_percentage)
fig.extra_y_ranges = {"Protein": Range1d(start=0, end=100)}
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Protein", axis_label='Protein %'), 'right')
fig.vbar(x='x',  top='y', 
         color='#27c738', width=0.75, 
         legend='Protein %', y_range_name= "Protein", source=source)

fig.line(x=months, y=130000, 
         color='purple', line_width=2,
         legend='Target 30%')
fig.line(x=months, y=240000, 
         color='red', line_width=2,
         legend='Calories Target 240000')

fig.line(x=months, y=calories, 
         color='#00b7f0', line_width=1,
         legend='Calories')
fig.y_range = Range1d(0, 400000)



fig.legend.location = 'top_right'

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ("month", "@x"),
        ("value", "@y")
    ]
)

# Let's check it out
fig.add_tools(hover)
show(fig)[enter image description here][1]
```

I expect to have my target line plots variables sharing two different y-axes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind switching over to matplotlib for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # x values
bar_ys = [28, 20, 10, 40, 10]  # left y axis
line_ys = [10, 20, 35, 40, 60]  # right y axis


fig, bar_ax = plt.subplots()
bar_ax.bar(xs, bar_ys, color='blue')  # plot first y series (line)
bar_ax.set_xlabel('x values')  # label for x axis
bar_ax.set_ylabel('bar values')  # label for left y axis
bar_ax.tick_params('y', colors='blue')  # add color to left y axis     

line_ax = bar_ax.twinx()
line_ax.plot(xs, line_ys, color='red')  # plot second y series (bar)
line_ax.set_ylabel('line values')  # label for right y axis
line_ax.tick_params('y', colors='red')  # add color to right y axis

plt.show()
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

To plot multiple line plots, simply add new calls to `line_ax.plot`, passing in new Y values in each call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # x values
bar_ys = [28, 20, 10, 40, 10]  # left y axis
line_ys_1 = [10, 20, 35, 40, 60]  # right y axis
line_ys_2 = [40, 40, 40, 40, 40]  # right y axis
line_ys_3 = [10, 20, 10, 20, 60]  # right y axis


fig, bar_ax = plt.subplots()
bar_ax.bar(xs, bar_ys, color='blue')  # plot first y series (line)
bar_ax.set_xlabel('x values')  # label for x axis
bar_ax.set_ylabel('bar values')  # label for left y axis
bar_ax.tick_params('y', colors='blue')  # add color to left y axis     

line_ax = bar_ax.twinx()
line_ax.plot(xs, line_ys_1, color='red')  # plot second y series (bar)
line_ax.plot(xs, line_ys_2, color='green')  # plot second y series (bar)
line_ax.plot(xs, line_ys_3, color='yellow')  # plot second y series (bar)
line_ax.set_ylabel('line values')  # label for right y axis

plt.show()
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

Essentially, you can use any combination of calls for `ax.plot`, `ax.bar` and any other plot type for the axes you get from `plt.subplots` and `ax.twinx`. Plots called on the same ax instance will share the same Y axis.

Comment: Thanks Very much, it helped a lot, I was really struggling with it!